# Wordpress LightSail AWS black screen

Tags: ssh, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a Wordpress website running in a Lightsail instance. I am using Bitnami, and something weird happened.
I was running some script to renew my certificate and suddenly my internet connection crashed. When I logged in back into my AWS Lightsail and tried to SSH again into the Wordpress instance, it get stuck on a black window.
I tried to reboot the instance and stop I and start it again but nothing, still the same issue.

After a while, while I had my SSH connection open (still in black screen) I rebooted the instance, doing this it force my black screen to show the login details and what I can see in the window, other than the Bitnami logo, is the following:

```
Last login: Tue Jul 13 19.58.55 2021 from my IP
could not chdir to home directory /home/bitnami: Permission Denied
/bin/bash: Permission denied
```

According to the screen, I was logged in all the time but I have a Permission denied issue which I believe it stops the instance from displaying any result.

Did anyone ever faced this issue and can help me to find a solution?

I read every where that they suggest to SSH from the terminal rather than the browser, but I don't have the SSH key for this instance as it get created automatically when they deployed it.

Comment: Bitnami developer here, the SSL certificate renewal uses the server's internet connection so it shouldn't be the cause of your local internet connection failure. I recommend mounting the disk on another server to check the permissions and I'd also check with AWS.

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. I solved the issue by creating a new instance from a snapshot I had. I don't know what happened and why The vm removed the permission. But all solved for now. Thank you again